# What exception will be caused If I forget close Spring MultipartFile?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

This is my method

```
public static void saveASoriginal(MultipartFile file,String FileName) throws IOException{
    BufferedImage srcImage=ImageIO.read(file.getInputStream());
    String imgType = "jpg";
    File saveFile = new File(FileName);
    if (!saveFile.exists()) {
        saveFile.mkdirs();
    }
    ImageIO.write(srcImage, imgType, saveFile);
}
```

In above method, I forget close object file, but I cannot find any exception in my production environment. Is that code correctly?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it. Although maybe a bit too long. You can use `file.transferTo(saveFile)` instead of what you have now. You only want to store the file on the filesystem, no need to make it more complex then that.

Answer (score 1):

No exception will happen,your application will run normally whether you use `SpringMVC` or not.

If you use `SpringMVC`,the container will mange it for yourself,you can use it just as an variable.

If you are not use `SpringMVC`,the only thing is that the application will not release the resource for `MultipartFile` util `JVM` garbage collected or or when the application ends . So your computer resource cost may be high for a period.

Comment: Well actually no that won't happen, assuming he is using the Spring `MultipartFile` support. Closing of the resource will be done by Spring, trying to mess with it yourself might even lead to exceptions from the framework. A rule of thumb, if you open a resource yourself you must close is. So if you haven't opened it, don't close it as that might (and probably will) lead to problems further down the line.

Comment: @M.Deinum we can close it by ourself,and I agree with your to check it before closing it

Comment: Read again... That is not what I'm saying. And as stated if you haven't opened it, you shouldn't be closing it. It should be closed at the same point where it was opened. Next to that Spring will close it for you.

Comment: Again that isn't what I'm saying... Even if it is open you shouldn't close it as you haven't opened it! You don't control the lifecycle of the `MultipartFile` something else is, as it got created and opened somewhere else.

Comment: @M.Deinum Okay,got it,I need further investigate for this in `springMVC`

Comment: @M.Deinum you are right,updated my answer and thank you